# My page won't publish

Tags: pages, publish

I hit 'publish' on a page a few days ago, and it is still not appearing on the website. Can you please help me fix this? 
Thank you,
Sarah

Comment: If it is a page you might need to add it to a menu to get it to show. Can you visit the page directly by it´s url? (ie. click on "view page" in the admin bar when you edit the page in question)

Comment: I'm sorry-- I misspoke-- it wasn't a page, but a post that won't update. When I click 'view post', I can see it how it should look, but it does not show up on the website. Thank you!

Comment: Without seeing some code, this is pretty much impossible to diagnose.

Comment: Hi Sarah. Can you give us the URL of the blog post (when you click View Post)?

Comment: Sure! It's: http://cwsrdu.org/2015/02/12/please-join-us-for-the-great-human-race/ 

but it should appear when you go to this website: http://cwsrdu.org/

Thank you so much!